# Keeping track of digits before operator sign

Tags: java, android, calculator

For a calculator program, I keep track of all digits before an operator sign and limit their numbers to 12 with a counter, when an operator sign is selected, it resets the counter to zero. The problem with this is that if I delete the sign and continue editing those previous numbers, the count isn't in effect anymore because it has been reset to 0 after the operator sign. It there an alternative way to go about this?

Thanks in Advance!

```js
private int numericCounter;
private boolean operatorAssigned;
private int cap = 12;


//if the number of digits is not 12, allow input
if (!(numericCounter >= cap)) {
  textView.append(button.getText());
}


//if an operator "+" "-"...
//is rececived set numeric counter to 0
if (operatorAssigned) {
  numericCounter = 0;
}

if (numericCounter == 0) {
  operatorAssigned = false;
}

//Notification
if (numericCounter >= cap) {
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  CharSequence text = "Maximum number of digits(12) reached";
  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
  //... show one Toast
  if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
  mToast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
  mToast.show();

  //show another Toast
  if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
  mToast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
  mToast.show();
}

//if maximum number of digits allowed
//not equal to 12
//increment numeric counter by 1
if (!(numericCounter >= cap)) {
  numericCounter++;
}

//Handles the delete button
findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {


    String text = textView.getText().toString();

    if ((!text.isEmpty() && resultComputed == false)) {
      String lastText = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
      textView.setText(lastText);
      lastNumeric = true;
      
      //Checks if deleted text is a digit or an operator
      if (lastText != "." || lastText != "+" || lastText != "-" || lastText != "/" || lastText != "/") {
        numericCounter--;
      }


    } else if ((!text.isEmpty() && resultComputed == true)) {
      textView.setText(txt);
      resultComputed = false;

    }



  }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps set a flag on startup/reset or whenever an operator is entered (or equals, or functions if/when you have those); clear the flag if an operator is deleted. If, when you enter a digit, the flag is set, _then_ reset the digit count.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a stack to keep a history of the counters. If you limit the stack to 2, you'll end up with the counter for the current number and the one for the previous number. Then, all you need to do is to manage the stack if you add/delete signs.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a backup variable. something like

```
private int backUp = 0;
```

Then in your `if(operatorAssigned)` function,
do this:

```
backUp = numericCounter;
numbericCounter = 0;
```

This way, if and when you check for your deletion of operator, just assign the value of `backUp` to your `numericCounter` again.

This is just a very basic idea.